# Overhead of declaring prototype of object on each instantiation?

Tags: javascript, prototype, private-members

So there has been much discussion on the topic of accessing private members inside of prototype methods. The thought occurred to me that the following should work:

```
function Test(){
    var private = "Private";
    this.instance = function(){
        return private;
    };

    Test.prototype.getPrivate = function(){
        return private;
    };
}
var test1 = new Test();
var test2 = new Test();
console.log(test1.instance === test2.instance);  // false
console.log(test1.getPrivate === test2.getPrivate);  // true
```

[Turns out](http://jsfiddle.net/8DBTq/) it does, in fact, work. I'm concerned, however, that there might be a drawback to doing this.

So my question is: Is there a drawback?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This doesn't work the way you probably expect, as `test1`'s `getPrivate()` gets `test2`'s private.

```
function Test(value){  
    var private = value;  
    this.instance = function(){ return private; };

    Test.prototype.getPrivate = function(){  
        return private;  
    };  
}  
var test1 = new Test("test1");  
var test2 = new Test("test2");
console.log(test1.getPrivate()); // test2
console.log(test2.getPrivate()); // test2
```

so it really doesn't matter if it is inefficient as it doesn't work.

Comment: You're right, but there's also some strange behavior: http://jsfiddle.net/8DBTq/1/

Comment: It is working as it is supposed to but not in a way you are expecting. The prototype is like a global variable. All instances share a single copy. If you modify it it will be modified for all instances.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you did make a mistake in defining the prototype function inside of the function itself. This way everytime an instance is generated the prototype method available to all instances is overwritten ... that's the strange thing you're seeing I guess.

```
function Test(param){
    var private = param;

    this._getPrivate = function(){
        return private;
    };    
}
Test.prototype.getPrivate = function(){
    return this.instance();
};     
var test1 = new Test("One");
var test2 = new Test(2);
console.log(test1.getPrivate());
console.log(test2.getPrivate());
```

This one works as expected.

But then, I don't understand what you need the prototype function for ... if you just defined the closure as a member-function, like you do (adding it to this instead of making it local), you get the same syntax as with using prototype. Hmmm, don't quite get what you intended - could it be you were just playing around with prototype?? *gg*

But then, if you're interested in accessing properties have a look at this code (EcmaScript 5 defineProperty) I took out of the - methinks - amazing prototypal tool (that comes without Prototypes drawbacks) Sugar ... (they actually use it to enable Events on PropertyChange! How very cool, anyway, doesn't work in legacy browsers <-> ES 5!)

```
Object.defineProperty(myObj, MyProp, {
    'enumerable'  : true,
    'configurable': true,
    'get': function() {
      return value;
    },
    'set': function(to) {
      value = calculateSomething(to);
    }
 });
```